# Informix. "Load from file" and indexes

Tags: informix

I need load big amount of data from file to table with many indexes on it.

What way faster, load data and after this create indexes or create indexes first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no question that loading the data first and creating the indexes subsequently is much faster. If it's messy to create the indexes separately for some reason, you can create them and then disable them for the period of the load:

`SET INDEXES, CONSTRAINTS ON table DISABLED;`

Load table and then run:

`SET INDEXES, CONSTRAINTS ON table ENABLED;`

Then `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the table according to best practice.

Having said all that, if speed is the issue, look at the High Performance Loader or even DBLoad. Either will be far more efficient than `LOAD FROM file.unl INSERT INTO table`.